# What is the best way to switch views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, performance, swiftui

I have tried several options to switch views in SwiftUI. However, each one had issues like lagging over time when switching back and forth many times. I am trying to find the best and cleanest way to switch views using SwiftUI. I am just trying to make a multiview user interface.

In `View1.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI
struct View1: View {
    @State var GoToView2:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if (GoToView2) {
                View2()
                //What should I do if I created another swiftui view under the name View2? 
                //Just calling View2() like that causes lag as described in the linked question before it was deleted, if from view2 I switch back to view1 and so on. 
                //If I directly put the code of View2 here, then adding other views would get too messy.
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {self.GoToView2.toggle()}) {
                        Text("Go to view 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `View2.swift`:

```
import SwiftUI
struct View2: View {
    @State var GoToView1:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if (GoToView1) {
                 View1()
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {self.GoToView1.toggle()}) {
                        Text("Go to view 1")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope the problem can be understood. To replicate the behavior, please compile the code in a SwiftUI app, then switch be repeatedly switching between the two buttons quickly for 30 seconds, then you should notice a delay between each switch, and resizing the window should look chunky. I am using the latest version of macOS and the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: No lags were observed. Can you show what do you do in View2? Which version of Xcode do you use?

Comment: @Asperi IF view2 goes has a button to go to view1, Then switching from 1 to 2 to 1 to 2 many times will build up lag. Try resizing the window, and it will resize chunky if laggy

Comment: I think this is because it is basically recursive... in `View1` you call `View2` and vice versa... it's like an infinite tree of views, right? You should pass `GoToView2` as a `Binding` to `View2`... Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @NoPhoneNumbers I tried your code and experienced lag when clicking on the buttons really quickly, but that could be a different problem ... my computer being slow, my phone being slow, the simulator, debugging mode ...

Comment: @krjw Did you notice that when clicking the buttons quickly it became more laggy as if each transition added a teeny bit of lag

Comment: @NoPhoneNumbers look at my answer and see what I have found. I think your method keeps on adding views, which could result in the behaviour that was experienced.

Comment: “The linked question have been deleted, I don't know why it was”—It was deleted, and the poster was given a temporary suspension, because the user was misbehaving (“The longer it tAKES to get an answer, the more I will bump with useless edits”).

Comment: @robmayoff Wait. But just because the _author_ misbehaves does not make the question bad and worthy of deletion

Comment: @robmayoff The question could have still helped future readers

Comment: I did not perform those actions. I am not a moderator. If you want to discuss the behavior and/or the response, please post on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I tried to show that each of the calls to the `Views` would add an instance to the view stack... I might be wrong here but the following should show this:

```
struct View1: View {
    @State var GoToView2:Bool = false
    var counter: Int

    init(counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter + 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (GoToView2) {
                Text("\(self.counter)")
                View2(counter: self.counter)
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.GoToView2.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Go to view 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @State var GoToView1:Bool = false
    var counter: Int

    init(counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter + 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (GoToView1) {
                Text("\(self.counter)")
                View1(counter: self.counter)
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.GoToView1.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Go to view 1")
                    }
                }.transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The I tried to show that the other method wouldn't do that:

```
struct View1: View {
    @State var GoToView2: Bool = false
    var counter: Int

    init(counter: Int) {
        self.counter = counter + 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (GoToView2) {
                Text("\(self.counter)")
                View2(counter: self.counter, GoToView1: self.$GoToView2)
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.GoToView2.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Go to view 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var GoToView1: Bool
    var counter: Int

    init(counter: Int, GoToView1: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._GoToView1 = GoToView1
        self.counter = counter + 1
    }

    var body: some View {

            VStack {
                Text("\(self.counter)")
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.GoToView1.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Go to view 1")
                }
            }.transition(.move(edge: .leading))


    }
}
```

I don't know if the lag is really coming from this or if there is a better method of proof, but for now this is what I came up with.

**Original answer**

I would recommend doing the following:

```
struct View1: View {
    @State var GoToView2:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if (GoToView2) {
                View2(GoToView1: self.$GoToView2)
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.GoToView2.toggle()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Go to view 2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    @Binding var GoToView1: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.GoToView1.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Go to view 1")
            }
        }.transition(.move(edge: .leading))
    }
}
```