# How do I switch views with swiftUI MacOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I found this question - [What is the best way to switch views in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59379043/12616999) - but I have not been able to get the answer to work for me.

```
struct view4x: View {

    @State var goView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        if goView {
            view5x(goView1: self.$goView)
        } else {
            Form {
                /* ... */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the button is inside the form:

```
Button(action: {
     self.goView.toggle()
}) {
     Text("Catalog")
}
```

and for my other view I have:

```
struct view5x: View {

    @Binding var goView1: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text("TEST")
        Button(action: {
            self.goView1.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Return")
        }
    }
}
```

I just get errors that both bodies declare an opaque return type. It does not preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here are similar mistakes in your views. To understand them better to look at `View` protocol:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol View {

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    associatedtype Body : View

    /// Declares the content and behavior of this view.
    var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

so, `body` is just a computed variable and it should return `some View`. Mistake in your `view5x` is that you put into it 2 different views instead 1. The solution here is to embed them into `VStack` for example:

```swift
struct view5x: View{

    @Binding var goView1: Bool

    var body: some View{

        VStack {
            Text("TEST")
            Button(action: {
                self.goView1.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Return")
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The problem it the `view4x` is similar - it's unclear what view returns body because of `if...else` statements, I think. You can fix it in the same way:

```swift
struct view4x: View {

    @State var goView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            if goView {
                view5x(goView1: $goView)
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.goView.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text("Catalog")
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

The other way is to say what view should body return if you wrap each of them into `AnyView` and type `return` before. In this example changes of `goView` don't switch views, but you can see the other syntax:

```swift
struct view4x: View {

    @State var goView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        if goView {
            return AnyView(view5x(goView1: $goView))
        } else {
            return AnyView(Button(action: {
                self.goView.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Catalog")
            })
        }


    }

}
```